# Specific query regard my javascript quiz

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon. My quiz question is  pretty specific. I really need help with one thing.  if you answer a question correctly, then go back to it, then click next, it adds to your total score again! So you can get infinite points if you want. I'm stumped on how to go about solving. I'm an amateur. Please take the time to help. Last time it was closed and I didnt get any guidance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Aldine Assessment</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<script type = "text/javascript">
    var quiz = [
            {
                "question"      :   "&nbsp Q1: What is the name of this school district?",
                "choices"       :   [   "&nbsp This is Aldine Independent School District.",
                                        "&nbsp This is Spring Independent School District.",
                                        "&nbsp This is Klein Independent School District.",
                                        "&nbsp This is Houston Independent School District."],
                "correct"       :   "&nbsp This is Aldine Independent School District.", },
            {
                "question"      :   "&nbsp Q2: What city are we currently located in ?",
                "choices"       :   [   "&nbsp We are currently located in the city of Spring.",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently located in the city of Houston.",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently located in the city of Dallas.",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently located in the city of San Antonio." ],
                "correct"       :   "&nbsp We are currently located in the city of Houston.",},
            {
                "question"      :   "&nbsp Q3:What state are we currently located in?",
                "choices"       :   [   "&nbsp We are currently located in the state of Texas.",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently located in the state of Louisiana.",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently located in the state of Atlanta.",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently located in the state of Florida."],
                "correct"       :   "&nbsp We are currently located in the state of Texas.",},
            {   
                "question"      :   "&nbsp Q4:What Department are we currently in?",
                "choices"       :   [
                                        "&nbsp We are part of the Financial Services Department.",
                                        "&nbsp We are part of the Child Nutrition Department",
                                        "&nbsp We are part of the Technology Services Department",
                                        "&nbsp We are part of the Child Development Department"],

                "correct"       :   "&nbsp We are part of the Technology Services Department",},
            {   
                "question"      :   "&nbsp Q5:What month are we currently in?",
                "choices"       :   [
                                        "&nbsp We are currently in the month of June",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently in the month of July",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently in the month of August",
                                        "&nbsp We are currently in the month of September"
                                    ],
                "correct"       :   "&nbsp We are currently in the month of June",},
 ];

        var currentQuestion = 0;
        var score = 0;
        var askingQuestion = true;
        var radioAnswer= new Array();



        function loadQuestion(){
            //---------------set temporary variable for creating radio buttons-------------------------
            var radioButton;
            //---------------clear out radio buttons from previous question----------------------------
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "";
            //---------------loop through choices, and create radio buttons----------------------------
            for(var i = 0; i < quiz[currentQuestion]["choices"].length; i++){
                radioButton  = document.createElement('input');
                radioButton.type = 'radio';
                radioButton.name = 'quiz'+currentQuestion;
                radioButton.id = 'choice'+ (i+1);
                if (radioAnswer[currentQuestion] == i)
                    {
                    radioButton.checked = true; 
                    }
                radioButton.value = quiz[currentQuestion]["choices"][i];
          //-------------------create label tag, which hold the actual text of the choices--------------
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                label.setAttribute('for','choice'+ (i+1));
                label.innerHTML = quiz[currentQuestion]["choices"][i];
          //-------------------------create a <br> tag to separate options-------------------------------
                var br = document.createElement('br');
                //attach them to content. Attach br tag, then label, then radio button

                document.getElementById('content').insertBefore(br, null);
                document.getElementById('content').insertBefore(label, br);
                document.getElementById('content').insertBefore(radioButton, label);
            }
        //----------------------------------load the question--------------------------------------------
            document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = quiz[currentQuestion]["question"];
        //---------------------------setup score for first time------------------------------------------
            if(currentQuestion == 0){
                document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = '<p>Score: 0 right answers out of ' + quiz.length +' possible</p>';
            }
        }

        function previous(){
        if(currentQuestion < quiz.length - 1){
                    currentQuestion--;
                    loadQuestion();
                } else {
                    showFinalResults();
                }
        }

        function checkAnswer(){

        //------------------------are we asking a question, or proceeding to next question?------------------
            if(askingQuestion){
        //---change button text to next question, so next time they click it, it goes to next question-------
                document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = 'Next Question';
                askingQuestion = false;
        //-------------------------determine which radio button they clicked---------------------------------
                var userpick;
                var correctIndex;
                var radios = document.getElementsByName('quiz'+currentQuestion);
                for(var i=0; i < radios.length; i++){
                    if(radios[i].checked){ //if this radio button is checked
                        userpick = radios[i].value;
                        radioAnswer[currentQuestion]= i;
                    }
        //-----------------------------------get index of correct answer-------------------------------------
                    if(radios[i].value == quiz[currentQuestion]["correct"]){
                        correctIndex = i;
                    }
                }
        //----------------------------set the color if they got it right, or wrong----------------------------
                if(userpick == quiz[currentQuestion]["correct"]){
                    score++;
                    document.getElementsByTagName('label')[correctIndex].style.color = "green";
                    document.getElementsByTagName('label')[correctIndex].style.fontWeight = "bold";
                } else {
                    document.getElementsByTagName('label')[correctIndex].style.color = "red";
                    document.getElementsByTagName('label')[correctIndex].style.fontWeight = "bold"; 
                }
                document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = '<p>Score: '+ score +' right answers out of ' + quiz.length +' possible</p>';
                } else { //reset form and move to next question
        //---------------------------------setting up so user can ask a question--------------------------------
                askingQuestion = true;
        //-------------------------------change button text back to 'submit answer'-----------------------------
                document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = 'Submit Answer';
        //-----------------------if we're not on last question, increase question number-------------------------
                if(currentQuestion < quiz.length - 1){
                    currentQuestion++;
                    loadQuestion();
                } else {
                    showFinalResults();
                }
            }
        }

        function showFinalResults(){

            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<h2>You Completed The Quiz</h2>';
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<p>Below are your results:</p>';
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<h2>' + score + ' out of ' + quiz.length + ' questions, ' + Math.round(score/quiz.length * 100) + '%<h2>';
            //-------------------------------delete the button------------------------------------------------------
            var button = document.getElementById('check');
            button.parentNode.removeChild(button); //js requires you to delete elements from the parent
            //--------------------------------remove question-------------------------------------------------------
            document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = "";
        }
        window.onload = loadQuestion;
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id = "box" class = "unhidden">

    <h2>This Is A Quiz Provided By Aldine ISD</h2>
    <h4> There will be no points awarded for unanswered questions.</h4>


    <div style="position:absolute; left:680px; top:150px">
        <img src="../AldineLogo1.png" alt="Picture Cannot Be Viewed">
    </div>

    <div style="position:absolute; left:690px; top:350px"><button id="check" class="submit"  onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit Answer</button > </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:690px; top:405px"><button id="check2" class="previous"  onclick="previous()">Previous Question</button > </div>
  <div id="frame">
      <h3 id="question">Question here</h3>
            <div id="content" ></div>
            <div id="response"></div> 
  </div>
  <div id="score"><h3>Score: 0 right answers out of 0 possible</h3></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In short, add a custom data attribute to your question elements, on next click, check this attribute to see if the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `answer` field to your `quiz` structure, so that it would be `question`,`choices`,`answer` in all records, and set it to -1 initially. Then, when user chooses an answer, store its value in this field. After that, check for `answer` value when displaying form and disable it, if current question is already answered.

Comment: Did I not do that already where answer is the same thing as "correct" in the array?

Comment: Well - no. As far as I can see, `correct` holds a copy of correct answer (by the way, why keeping another copy of a long string, when you can store index of correct answer and compare radio button position to it?). What you need is a flag, that shows, that you are already pass this question.

Comment: So would I do something along the lines of what I did with radioAnswer? Im sorry. Its not sticking.

Comment: @DerekLockett yes, you should store an index of an answer in this field. Then, every time you want to output a question, check for that value, and if it's not "-1" - don't output question and write something like "you have already answered this".